# Query: How to get both Question and multi Answers in one query

Tags: mysql

For this question, `Question` and `Answer` are just my example tables for one-many relationship. For example: `Question(QuestionID, QuestionTitle, QuestionContent)` and `Answer(AnswerID, AnswerContent, QuestionID)`

In one query, I want to get one question and all answers of this question by QuestionID:

1. How to write a query like that
2. In case that, I "think" will have each rows is an answer with additional fields of question. This will make duplication because all those answers have same question content --> cost memory to store additional data. So compare to this: get QuestionID and query get Question. get QuestionID and query to get all Answers. Does this way lost performance than first approach but gain more memory ?

Here is my script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Question` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Question` (
  `QuestionID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `QuestionContent` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`QuestionID`),
ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Answer` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Answer` (
  `AnswerID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `QuestionID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ReplyContent` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AnswerID`),
  INDEX `fk_Answer_Question1_idx` (`QuestionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Answer_Question1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`QuestionID`)
    REFERENCES `Question` (`QuestionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Make a `JOIN` with `Question.QuestionID = Answer.QuestionID`?. Make a subquery with all the QuestionID you want to filter in `Answer.QuestionID IN (SELECT QuestionID FROM Question WHERE QuestionID='1');`

Comment: will join more performance than query individual table? thanks :)

Comment: The performance comes having a normalized database with all its components (indexes, engines, etc).

Comment: can you tell me more, please. in case in index questionID and answerID, and I use InnoDB. thanks :)

Comment: Add in your question your `CREATE TABLE` scripts of `Answer` and `Question` please.

Comment: @oNare I have edited my question :)

Comment: It would be a challenge to use it as a multiple-choice question/multiple-answer model. You would have to add a `correct` column to the `Answer` table. Then, it gets interesting.

Comment: Can you tell me interesting part of multiple-choice answer,please. As you said, I will added isCorrected into Answer table. and I can filter by making condition for this field. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You could make it with a simple `JOIN`, the question is: Are you going to have others tables?. That could make that you have to redo your design. I suggest [EAV](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49618/to-eav-or-not-to-eav) if you're going to use more tables with some configuration between `Questions` and `Answers`.

With your actual design the query would be like:

```
mysql> SELECT 
    -> q.QuestionID,
    -> q.QuestionContent,
    ->     a.AnswerID,
    ->     a.ReplyContent
    -> FROM test.Question AS q
    -> JOIN test.Answer AS a ON (a.QuestionID=q.QuestionID)
    -> WHERE q.QuestionID=1;
+------------+------------------------------+----------+--------------+
| QuestionID | QuestionContent              | AnswerID | ReplyContent |
+------------+------------------------------+----------+--------------+
|          1 | How many indexes may I have? |        1 | Use 6        |
|          1 | How many indexes may I have? |        2 | Use 1        |
|          1 | How many indexes may I have? |        3 | A or B       |
+------------+------------------------------+----------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT 
    -> q.QuestionID,
    -> q.QuestionContent,
    ->     a.AnswerID,
    ->     a.ReplyContent
    -> FROM test.Question AS q
    -> JOIN test.Answer AS a ON (a.QuestionID=q.QuestionID)
    -> WHERE q.QuestionID=1;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys           | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | q     | const | PRIMARY                 | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL   | fk_Answer_Question1_idx | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Related:

- [To EAV or not to EAV?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49618/to-eav-or-not-to-eav)
- [Efficient query for an advanced EAV model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68679/efficient-query-for-an-advanced-eav-model/69278#69278)
- [Eav MySQL Search](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=eav)

Comment: Can you tell me about "EAV"? And can you tell me performance when I query on each table rather than using join ? thanks :)

Comment: I've added a link in the answer. You could search all over dba.SE and you will find good solution to your question.

Comment: BTW I borrowed your code for my answer, so +1 for copyright infringement.

Answer (score 2):

Just borrowing [**the code from oNare's answer**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107257/877), I have a suggesion

If you want to show the Question just once and all the Answers, there is a fancy trick you can do by aggregating the answers into a single field using the [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functions

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
SELECT 
    q.QuestionID,
    q.QuestionContent,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(a.AnswerID,':',a.ReplyContent) ORDER BY a.AnswerID) AllTheAnswers
FROM test.Question AS q
JOIN test.Answer AS a ON (a.QuestionID=q.QuestionID)
WHERE q.QuestionID=1
GROUP BY q.QuestionID;
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, but if he need the exactly `AnswerID` for frontend ambient and CRUDs. You could use  `SEPARATOR '\n'` if you want `AllTheAnswers` vertically.

Comment: @oNare If this were for a PHP script, one could take `AllTheAnswers` and run PHP's explode function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) using the colon(`:`) as the delimiter. Then, the array is open to individualize the display of each answer.